# Cordova CLI Explanation

Tags: cordova, crosswalk, crosswalk-project

When creating a cordova app with the command prompt, I'm cannot figure out what one part is for.  Take the follow command " cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld". Obviously hello is the folder, HelloWord is the app name, but what is the com.example.hello for? How is it figured out and what does it do?

Comment: `com.example.hello` is package name OR package ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Id attribute specified in config.xml or mentioned in CLI while creating project specifies the app's domain identifier. While building android platform for instance, this id will end up as package name in AndroidManifest.xml which unique for each application.

Check out the [official cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/#widget) for more info.